# Firebase does not sort items by date correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am filtering some documents by date / time to retrieve the most recent items first.

However, when adding a new item to the list it is added correctly, but when restarting the app the list is redone and the items are arranged at random, which should not be happening because I am ordering by date.

It could be that I am doing this to add these items to the list.

**I'm doing it like this:**

```
Future<void> _addListernerFavoritos() async{
  favoritosModel.limparLista();
  List<String> listaBackp = [];

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("usuarios")
      .doc(usuario.idUsuario)
      .collection("favoritos")
      .orderBy("data", descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {

    snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) async{
      String idEmpresa = change.doc.id;

      switch (change.type) {
        case DocumentChangeType.added:
        //========== quando um favorito for adicionado ==========

          DocumentSnapshot docEmp = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("empresas")
              .doc(idEmpresa)
              .get();

          Empresa empresa = Empresa.fromDocumentSnapshot(docEmp);
          if(!favoritosModel.listFavoritos.contains(empresa)){
            //favoritosModel.addFavoritos(empresa);
            favoritosModel.insertFavorito(0, empresa);
          }

          break;
        case DocumentChangeType.modified:
        //========== modificado ==========
          break;
        case DocumentChangeType.removed:
        //========== removido ==========
          favoritosModel.removeWhere(idEmpresa);
          listaBackp.add(idEmpresa);
          break;
      }
    });

    //_sort();
  });
}
```

**The model I'm using to update the list is this:**

```
class FavoritosModel = _FavoritosModel with _$FavoritosModel;

abstract class _FavoritosModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<Empresa> listFavoritos = ObservableList();

  @action
  void insertFavorito(int index, Empresa value){
    listFavoritos.insert(index, value);
  }

  @action
  void addFavoritos(Empresa value) {
    listFavoritos.add(value);
  }

  @action
  void removeWhere(String idEmpresa){
    listFavoritos.removeWhere((empresa) => idEmpresa == empresa.idEmpresa);
  }

  @action
  void limparLista(){
    listFavoritos.clear();
  }

  @action
  void attEmpresa(int index, Empresa value){
    listFavoritos.removeWhere((empresa) => empresa.idEmpresa == value.idEmpresa);
    listFavoritos.insert(index, value);
  }

}
```

**My listView looks like this:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      color: Cores.COR_CINZA_BACKGROUND,
      child: Observer(
        builder: (_){
          FavoritosModel favoritosModel = GetIt.I<FavoritosModel>();
          ObservableList<Empresa> listFavoritos = favoritosModel.listFavoritos;

          if(listFavoritos.length == 0){
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
              child: Center(
                child: TextApp(
                  text: "Você ainda não adicionou nenhuma empresa aos favoritos",
                  fontSize: 16,
                  textColor: Cores.COR_DARK_LIGTH,
                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                  centralizar: true,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            //reverse: true,
            itemCount: listFavoritos.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){

              Empresa empresa = listFavoritos[index];

              if(empresa == null){
                return Container();
              }

              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  push(context, TelaEmpresa(empresa: empresa));
                },
                  child: CardEmpresa(empresa: empresa, favoritos: true,));
            },
          );

        },
      ),
    );

  }
```

In my view everything is correct, I do not understand why it is not sorting by date. can anybody help me?

**I have already tried to save the date in these two ways and neither works:**

```
Timestamp getDataFiltro(){
  var now = new Timestamp.now();
  return now;
}

String getDateNow(){
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  return now.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you created an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for that query?

Comment: Yes, the problem is occurring in the .sort that is not sorting the list by date correctly

Comment: Even sorting by date correctly, I get something like this:
I/flutter (28507): data favorito 21-03-2021
I/flutter (28507): data favorito 22-03-2021
I/flutter (28507): data favorito 21-03-2021
I/flutter (28507): data favorito 21-03-2021
I/flutter (28507): data favorito 20-03-2021
I/flutter (28507): data favorito 21-03-2021

Comment: Eventually the filter works and the data coincides with the respective dates. But when you open and close the app, the data is randomly organized again.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved.**

To solve this problem I had to call the `favoritosModel.sort();` in all listen changes.

Below I leave the listen with the changes made to help new people who have this same problem:

```
Future<void> _addListernerFavoritos() async{
    favoritosModel.limparLista();
    List<String> listaBackp = [];

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("usuarios")
        .doc(usuario.idUsuario)
        .collection("favoritos")
        .orderBy("data", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {

      snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) async{
        String idEmpresa = change.doc.id;
        Timestamp dataFiltro = change.doc["data"];

        switch (change.type) {
          case DocumentChangeType.added:
          //========== quando um favorito for adicionado ==========

            DocumentSnapshot docEmp = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("empresas")
                .doc(idEmpresa)
                .get();

            Empresa empresa = Empresa.fromDocumentSnapshot(docEmp);
            empresa.dataFiltro = dataFiltro;
            if(!favoritosModel.listFavoritos.contains(empresa)){
              //favoritosModel.insertFavorito(0, empresa);
            }
            favoritosModel.addFavoritos(empresa);

            favoritosModel.sort();
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.modified:
          //========== modificado ==========
            favoritosModel.sort();
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.removed:
          //========== removido ==========
            favoritosModel.removeWhere(idEmpresa);
            favoritosModel.sort();
            listaBackp.add(idEmpresa);
            break;
        }
      });

      favoritosModel.sort();
    });

 }
```

I would also like to thank everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `.orderBy("date", descending: true)` instead of `.orderBy("data", descending: true)`? (Change "data" to "date")

Comment: I continue with the problem. What would be the difference? You just changed the name of the field. Nothing changes.

Comment: I thought its maybe a misspelling of the name of your date-field. What is the name of your date-field in firebase?

Comment: "data". It recovers items correctly by date. The problem I make another query within this listen (as shown in the code above). Alas, the items are not ordered correctly.

Comment: You can order the list with the command sort before using it in the build-function:  myList.sort((a, b) => a.data.compareTo(b.data))

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that. However, most of the time the data is shown in the list at random. Eventually they are sorted correctly, but when relogging the data are listed at random again.